# How to change column separation of two column footnote [memoir]

Tags: luatex, footnotes, memoir, two-column

With the document class `memoir` and use of the built-in footnote setting `\twocolumnfootnotes`, how do you:

- Change the size of the column seperation to e.g. 0.2cm?

LuaTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{% hide footenote ruler
  \hrule width 0pt
}

\renewcommand{\@twocolfootfmt}[1]{%
  \@preamtwofmt
  {%
    \hspace*{-\footparindent}%
    \footfootmark%
    \strut {\foottextfont #1}\strut\par}\allowbreak}

\renewcommand{\@preamtwofmt}{%
  \hsize .45\hsize
  \parindent=\z@
  \tolerance=5000\relax
  \parindent=\footparindent%
  \leavevmode}

\makeatother

\setlength\footmarkwidth{1em}
\setlength\footparindent{1.5em}
\footmarkstyle{\hbox to \footmarkwidth{\textsuperscript{#1}\hfil}}

\makeatletter % custom footnotes without numbering
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}

\makeatother

\twocolumnfootnotes

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

text\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}\footnote{\lipsum[3-5]} text text

\end{document}
```

*PS I somehow can't combine this with the normal way of going about this with `\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2.cm}`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The `\@preamtwofmt` macro in your MWE sets the width of the columns to be `.45\hsize` thus the separation is `.1\hsize`. In your version of `\@preamtwofmt`

```
\renewcommand{\@preamtwofmt}{%
  \hsize = X\hsize
  \parindent=\z@
  \tolerance= 5000\relax
  \raggedright
  \leavevmode}
```

where you have to choose the value of X to give you the column separation that you want; the value will depend on the `\hsize` (textwidth) of your document.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It takes some time to get used to, that is, the memoir document class, documentation and customization.. Learning along the way here, thanks again